# julia - Throwing and printing errors from @async Tasks

Tags: julia

How do I make julia show exceptions when they are thrown from an async task?

```
@async while true:
   sleep(100)
   error("test")
end
```

I know one way is to wrap them in a sync block:

```
@sync @async while true:
   sleep(100)
   error("test")
end
```

However, how can I make this work when I need to return control to the caller?

```
function connect()
    # This blocks forever, but I need to return control to caller 
    @sync @async while true:
       sleep(100)
       error("test")
    end
end

connect()
do_something_else()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can allow printing of errors by using a try catch block in the async block:

```
function connect()
    @async while true:
       try
           sleep(100)
           error("test")
       catch e
           break
       end
    end
end
```